# What is the nomenclature for an object that listens on a generic server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I want to create a generic `Server` class that has the following

- a client manager
- a room manager

This `Server` could be extended to be a

- chat server
- game server
- etc

I want to be able to re-use this `Server` class *without* it knowing what kind of server it is. That is, it could be

- UDP
- TCP
- WebSocket
- HTTP

What kind of object do I create to listen on to any of the above socket types? Am I creating a `SocketListener`? A `ServerListener`? I am asking this not because I cannot decide on a class name, but because I don't really understand what I'm "listening" on. If I am listening on a socket, what differentiates my listening socket from a client's socket? Is it because it the client has a different IP? A different file descriptor?

Comment: I think every protocol is a separate listener

Comment: I seems to me that what you want is a single function to use as the callback for data coming through ANY kind of connection. Back in the day I had created a class `DataFetcher` to hook up to any InputStream(https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java) is what you're thinking about something like this?

Comment: *Connection*Handler, *Protocol*Handler?

Comment: hmm tough one. My first thought would be to make use of a custom EventEmitter. So you create your generic Server class that in the constructor expects an object that is of the type/instance of your custom EventEmitter. Now for each type of server (UDP,TCP,WebSocket or HTTP) you create a class that extends from your custom EventEmitter. Now your custom EventEmitter should emit events like 'onConnection' 'onData' etc. Emit these events from your HTTP,TCP versions with their own impl. That way your generic server does not care what goes in as long what goes in follows the correct interface